# Project structure in meteor and problems with import

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am new to meteor and i use it to create a webgl application for mobile devices.

My problem is the file structure. I already read the manuals so pls dont link to them.

1.The `lib` gets loaded first , so i put all my code that should be executed in `main.js` there?(i.g. for my webgl project i use a lot of oop, so does it make sense to put my code here?)

2.Consider the following structure
[image]

Everything i use for the webgl application is in the `src` folder, but if i want to `Application.run();` i always get the error `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'src/Application.js'`. This problem occurs in every folder i put the `src` folder in, wether it is `lib` or `import` or whatever.

My `Application.js` looks like this:

```
var Application={};
Application.run = function () {

        //code

}
module.exports = Application;
```

But what i really want for `Application.js` is:

```
function Application(){
  //some stuff
}
Application.prototype.run = function(){
   //some stuff
}
```

So how can i use the second approach of `application.js` in `main.js` AND if its not possible how should i do it instead?

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot, it looks like your `Application.js` file is actually named just `Application` (without the `.js` extension).

That may be the reason why your project does not find `'src/Application.js'`.

Comment: thx for the feedback. By any chance, have you tried `import {Application} from 'src/Application'` (without the `.js` file extension)? You could also try appending `./` at the beginning of your path.

Comment: Yes i tried this too. In changed the code to es6 'export default class' and this seems to work. Since this isnt a solution to my answer, i didnt mark it as answer.

Comment: Sure, thx for the feedback anyway. You should consider writing the solution that worked for you as a full answer and auto-accept it.